# Does a streak of poorly received questions not affect a high-rep poster?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, question-quality

I'm asking this question because recently I've been seeing something which puzzles me quite a bit.

In one of the tags I follow there's one high-rep user who is on a streak of poorly received questions. The last 10 ones or so (maybe more) all have a negative score, some are closed. I can imagine why, the reason I myself would downvote them is because they look rather lazy.

In fact, the ones that are not closed go on to receive answers from high-rep answerers.

The message I'm getting from this is:

> "these kind of questions do not fit the standard, but we will answer them anyway".

##### **Why?**

I'm all about helping other fellow programmers, but this seems contradictory. I understand that downvotes and flags on answers convey two very different meanings.

On the other hand, I don't see this for questions. If you downvote a question, and even more so if you vote to close it, you are essentially saying: "this post has problems", for example: it doesn't include enough details, it's poorly formatted, it's not reproducible, it doesn't show effort, etc. Which are more or less the same reasons available when flagging for close.

---

Does a streak of poorly received questions **not** affect the poster in any way? If they keep contributing content that doesn't pass scrutiny, I would expect that to reflect on them somehow.

So what is going on? Are poorly received questions fine, as long as they can reasonably be of help to others? What is the rule of thumb?

Comment: they exist in every tag and it is sometimes frustrating, it helps overall to keep a higher level of questions and answers

Comment: A streak of poorly received questions can end up on question ban if the user doesn't have a lot of reputation. Users with enough rep seem to be immune to the post-ban algorithm. Voting and flagging those posts when appropriate is totally fine, though.

Comment: It might be time to let a moderator know by raising a confidential flag on one of their posts and highlighting the pattern of recent, low-quality questions. As others have pointed out, our automatic quality-control systems are not designed to handle cases where a high-rep user suddenly starts posting low-quality questions that don't meet our standards.

Comment: @CodyGray what is a "confidential flag"? Do you mean a custom flag?

Comment: "there's one high-rep user," - high-rep is the keyword here. High rep often means it's a lot harder to get an asking/answering ban, for algorithmic reasons us mortals will never actually know. Raising a mod flag is really the only option for dealing with that type of behavior from high-rep users

Comment: Yes, I mean a custom flag. I used the word "confidential" to make clear that moderator flags are confidential, which avoids concerns about publicly calling out a particular user (which you wouldn't want to do on Meta).

Comment: @CodyGray thanks. I just flagged the most recent question with a custom flag

Comment: @CodyGray follow up on your first comment: how many poorly received questions would you think is a reasonable threshold for flagging? In this OP I mentioned ~10. Is that it? Can it be less? Should it be more?

Comment: Whatever you think would be enough for a moderator to take action. Use your own judgment; we do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A streak of poorly received questions does not *really* impact users with relatively high reputation.

Based on the ban message and observed ban cases to hit the ban one needs to have consistently non-positive average contribution in questions or answers correspondingly (there are likely other factors but average votes seem to have the most impact). So if one occasionally posts useful questions it is very likely to outweigh all negative contribution. Additionally negative votes are essentially capped to 3 (to allow deletion) and in super rare cases reach 10-15 (posts that are either outrageously rude or asking for malicious code) while upvotes are unbounded  - this makes it even less likely to meet condition of the ban.

For possible action as [Cody Gray said in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398811/does-a-streak-of-poorly-received-questions-not-affect-the-poster#comment778813_398811) use custom flag if you feel necessary:

> ...by raising a confidential flag on one of their posts and highlighting the pattern of recent, low-quality questions.
> ...Yes, I mean a custom flag. I used the word "confidential" to make clear that moderator flags are confidential, which avoids concerns about publicly calling out a particular user (which you wouldn't want to do on Meta).

Using a custom flag is especially recommended when you are tempted to downvote all recent questions by the author triggering "revenge downvote" pattern. This is very likely to happen in such "streak of bad questions" cases ("you <strike>*censored*</strike> posted 4 nearly identical questions and did not even look at comments"). If that happens the safest option is to custom flag and to consider ignoring posts from that user for some time for your own sake.

Note so that lack of research alone does not make the question off-topic on Stack Overflow. Such questions are still eligible for answers and may even eventually collect positive votes as being useful (ideally someone would improve question too, but that is not strictly required).

Answer (score 2):

You are asking two questions. How can questions both be downvoted and receive quality answers and how does having questions downvoted affect users?

The answer to the first question is that in this situation it is not the same people that downvote the questions that answer them. Those who downvote them think they are of poor quality and those that answer them think they are of sufficient quality. How can two groups of people come to so different conclusions? My hunch is that the downvoters is of the organizing type and try to improve SO by weeding out low-quality content. Thus, they judge questions based on indirect qualities such as well-formattedness and how many points the user asking the question has. But those who answer the question are often domain experts and can see past such issues. A domain expert in X doesn't need a question about X to be perfectly formulated to be able to answer it. Those who answer those questions demonstrate that they are of sufficient quality so the "organizers" should reevaluate and maybe change their downvotes to upvotes. That rarely happens since the downvoting generally preceedes the answering.

The answer to the second question is that for many votes does not have an impact. Up and downvotes is a reward and punishment system for those that buy into the system. But for many, their SO score is "imaginary internet points" and for those up and downvoting is ineffective in modulating their behavior.

Comment: I cannot quite agree with the second paragraph: Being able to answer a question and finding it useful are two different things. Just because I as an expert can link the question to the answer doesn't mean that *non experts with a similar problem* will be able to link their (hypothetical) question to the low-quality question or expert answer; that makes them inherently less/not useful. Another expert demonstrating different quality criteria doesn't change mine.

Comment: I think answering implies that the answering party thinks the question is useful. Most people try to take all relevant factors into account when evaluating quality. The existence of a useful answer from a high-rep user is a relevant factor. So not so much a question of different quality criteria, but rather of one not understanding why the evaluated question passes the quality criteria.

Comment: I found a few of those questions reasonable and have up-voted them accordingly.

Comment: If you question is not rhetorical you can post that question on this SO site.

Comment: I feel that your (rethorical?) questions are about improving your behavior, not about my answer. So ask the community, not me. Also, [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).