# Which user has asked the most questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

From my understanding, most users who stick around past asking a question have answered more questions than asked questions. It is no doubt that asking questions is an extremely effective and important way to contribute to Stack Overflow. There are some users who have asked a lot of questions. Out of curiosity, I was wondering who has asked the most?

The other day I came across [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181365/learner). With 360 questions asked, impressively many of these questions are of high-quality and are meaningful contributions to the site. I also found it interesting that the user had not answered any questions (other than their own).

This leads me to the follow-up question:
Which user has asked the most questions but with 0 answers? Essentially the converse to [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) (with an eye-watering 85,105 answers but no questions).

Comment: *"most users on Stack Overflow have answered more questions than asked questions"*, I am _highly_ doubtful of this. I would expect most users ask one question and never return, meanwhile if people are answering I'd wager they generally answer multiple.

Comment: @Nickistired That is true, I hadn't fully considered that. Maybe I should have said the average (mean) user has more answers than questions? I'll edit the post to make my point clearer.

Comment: Well, your "*this user*" with 360 Qt's is nearly nothing, here is a "notorious" [Serial Asker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593077) (=> 1.36k Qt's + 1.58k Answers), well "notorious" because they regularly post on 'Meta' each time they notice a few Downvotes on their Qt's... // Would need to run a Query on 'SEDE' to find the "ultimate" Answer to your Qt...!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. I was perplexed to see all the downvotes on this post - what should I do differently next time I post on this Meta?

Comment: There are also many users who have literally asked 1,000 - 2,000 ***low-quality*** questions, suggesting the site is being used contrary to what it is intended for. For example, the notorious "ooo" (now by a different name). Related: *[What should I do about an experienced user with a history of asking bad questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416814/)*

Comment: @MorganS42 you don't need to do anything differently, voting on meta works differently and often implies "you're wrong" or "don't want". A highly downvoted question (and 14 downvotes is pretty mild) can have value. In this case I can imagine that people don't really appreciate the intrusive nature of the question, you are essentially asking that people get put in the spotlight without their permission for no real good reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From SEDE ("null" user is posts from deleted users I think). Query results taken since the last SEDE refresh at the time of this writing:

#### Questions (Including Deleted and Closed)

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1768011

```sql
-- By Questions (Including Deleted and Closed)
SELECT TOP 20
  COUNT(*) AS QuestionIncludingDeletedAndClosedCount,
  P.OwnerUserId AS [User Link]
FROM PostsWithDeleted P
--JOIN Users U ON U.Id = P.OwnerUserId
WHERE
  P.PostTypeId = 1 -- Questions
GROUP BY P.OwnerUserId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
;
```

#### Non-Deleted Questions (Including Closed)

I got the same result as with including deleted and closed posts for some reason. Not sure why. I suspect I wrote one of the queries wrong.

#### Non-Deleted, Non-Closed Questions

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1768013

```sql
-- By Non-Deleted, Non-Closed Questions
SELECT TOP 20
  COUNT(*) AS NonDeletedNonClosedQuestionCount,
  P.OwnerUserId AS [User Link]
FROM Posts P
--JOIN Users U ON U.Id = P.OwnerUserId
WHERE
  P.PostTypeId = 1 -- Questions
  AND P.ClosedDate IS NULL
GROUP BY P.OwnerUserId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
;
```

#### Combined table of results

| QuestionIncludingDeletedAndClosedCount | NonDeletedNonClosedQuestionCount | User Link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11324235 | 464214 | null |
| 3025 | 2778 | [David542](https://stackoverflow.com/users/651174) |
| 2625 | 2552 | [Blankman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39677) |
| 2371 | 2261 | [B. Clay Shannon-B. Crow Raven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875317) |
| 2040 | 1938 | [membersound](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1194415) |
| 1939 | 1809 | [Peter Penzov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103606) |
| 1926 | 1852 | [blue-sky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470184) |
| 1856 | 1763 | [Alex Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/117700) |
| 1814 | 1736 | [leora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653) |
| 1696 | 1655 | [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235929) |
| 1689 | 1660 | [AnApprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149080) |
| 1685 | 1617 | [Alexander Mills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1223975) |
| 1652 | 1556 | [AndreaNobili](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1833945) |
| 1575 | 1409 | [TIMEX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179736) |
| 1528 | 1475 | [mpen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65387) |
| 1491 | 1454 | [ProfK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8741) |
| 1465 | 1401 | [nonopolarity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325418) |
| 1440 | 1344 | [Alan2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422604) |
| 1425 | 1386 | [Cheok Yan Cheng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72437) |
| 1407 | 1347 | [quarks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785349) |

Comment: FYI, `PostWithDeleted` doesn't expose who the author of the post is when the post is deleted, which is why you get such a high volume of `NULL` values.

Comment: @ThomA ah. that would also explain why I got the same result as with non-deleted, closed questions as with my attempt with all questions including deleted and closed.

Comment: Would it also be possible to show the number of answers by these users?  It would be interesting to see how many are primarily (or only) asking.

Comment: The Header of the 1st Column is not correct, I think: "*QuestionIncludingDeletedAndClosedCount*". I (only) have 0.6k-Rep (=> <10k, so I don't see 'Deleted Questions'), but for the #1 and #2, if I look at their Profile, I also get the exact same numbers: 3025 + 2625. => 'Deleted Qt's' are not included, and the Header then is stg like "QuestionNonDeletedAndIncludingClosedCount"...

Comment: @dbush yes, possible. but that's a different question. Also, I'd (personally) prefer that SEDE questions that don't necessarily have to do with a specific site get asked on MSE or in https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede.

Answer (score 1):

In case one wonders about questions on the entire Stack Exchange network, see
[Who asked the most number of questions on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284601/178179), which links to this [network-wide SEDE  query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/540572) that sorts users by number of posted questions on the entire Stack Exchange network. Note that, due to SEDE limitations, it ignores deleted questions.